# a single click-event for multiple functions

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following code:

```
$('#picture-div').click(function(){
    $('#div-in-document').fadeToggle('slow', $func1);
});
$('#picture-div2').click(function(){
    $('#div-in-document2').fadeToggle('slow', $func2);
});
```

I'm trying to make this into one single click event, but can't seem to make it work. I've tried the following:

```
$('#picture-div ,#picture-div2').click(function(){
    if($(this) == '#picture-div')
        $('#div-in-document').fadeToggle('slow', $func);
    else
        $('#div-in-document2').fadeToggle('slow', $func2);
});
```

But that always go to the `else`, so my if-statement is invalid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your markup using `data-*` attributes like:

```
<div class="picture-div" data-target="someId">...</div>
<div class="picture-div" data-target="someOtherId">...</div>
```

And your js will be just:

```
var yourFunctions = {
  someId : function(){...}.
  someOtherId : function(){...}
}

$('.picture-div').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $('#' + target).fadeToggle('slow', yourFunctions[target]);
});
```

Maintainability is safe, hoorray.

Comment: Looks like the person who was correct deleted his post(?). Anyway, I tried this, and it worked very well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('#picture-div ,#picture-div2').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == '#picture-div')
        $('#div-in-document').fadeToggle('slow', $func);
    else
        $('#div-in-document2').fadeToggle('slow', $func2);
});
```

Or you can make a kind of mapping:

```
var arr = [ { selector: "#picture-div", subselector: "#div-in-document", func: $func1},
            { selector: "#picture-div2", subselector: "#div-in-document2", func: $func2}]
```

and go through it for assigning handler:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    $(arr[i].selector).click(function(){
      $(arr[i].subselector).fadeToggle('slow', arr[i].func);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead and I hope it will work

```
$('#picture-div ,#picture-div2').click(function(){
    if($(this) == $('#picture-div'))
        $('#div-in-document').fadeToggle('slow', $func);
    else
        $('#div-in-document2').fadeToggle('slow', $func2);
});
```

I have not tested it but I am pretty sure that it will work

Comment: If I click one, both is displayed, so not working. The same happens with Zenith suggestion

Comment: Can you please paste the code for your div as well because according to me the above code should work

Comment: heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/cvHdQ/ (line 32-35 is the relevant code)

Comment: but I think this is the same as I have written above. Please let me know if there is some difference